# Is it possible to run a hidden console application from a Windows service?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, service, delphi-2010, console-application

I've written a server in Delphi 2010 that needs to launch a console application every now and again to back up a database. The console application can send log information to the console window, but it is not required.

This works fine when running as an application, but when run as a service I get an access violation when launching the console application. This is the case even if I launch it hidden (SW_HIDE).

Is it possible to launch a hidden console application from a Windows service? The solution needs to work on XP, Vista and Windows 7.

EDIT: The access violation happens when I call ShellExecute.

Comment: How are you launching your console app (code)? We are using CreateProcess(W) to launch console apps from a service and catch their output and don't have any problems.

Comment: Is it a military secret, where exactly did you get access violation? Is it you launch code or it's console app, who crashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `ShellExecute`, then don't: it won't work inside a service, and is almost never the best way to start a process.

Use `CreateProcess` in stead.

See this bunch of [ShellExecute / CreateProcess question threads on stackoverflow](http://www.google.com/search?q=createprocess+shellexecute+site:stackoverflow.com).

--jeroen